# use of FOR UPDATE statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using PL/SQL (Oracle 11g) to update the `EMPLOYEES` table salary column.

I have used two separate scripts to do the same thing i.e update the salary of employees.

One script uses `FOR UPDATE OF` statement where as another script doesn't uses it. In both cases I found that oracle holds the row level locks until we execute the `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT` commands.

Then what is the difference in between two scripts?

Which one is better to use?

Here are the two scripts I am talking about:

```
-- Script 1: Uses FOR UPDATE OF

declare
cursor cur_emp
is
select employee_id,department_id from employees where department_id = 90 for update of salary;
begin
  for rec in cur_emp
  loop
    update Employees
    set salary = salary*10
    where current of cur_emp;
   end loop;
end;


--Script 2: Does the same thing like script 1 but FOR UPDATE OF is not used here

declare
cursor cur_emp
is
select employee_id,department_id from employees where department_id = 90;
begin
  for rec in cur_emp
  loop
    update Employees
    set salary = salary*10
    where Employee_ID = rec.employee_id;
   end loop;
end;
```

I found that Oracle acquired the row level locks on both cases. So, what is the benefit of using `FOR UPDATE OF` and Which is the better way of coding?

Comment: Dont forget:  if employee == mrp then set salary += 100000

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you specify `FOR UPDATE`, the row is locked at the point that you `SELECT` the data.  Without the `FOR UPDATE`, the row is locked at the point you `UPDATE` the row.  In the second script, another session could potentially lock the row between the time that the `SELECT` was executed and the point that you tried to `UPDATE` it.

If you are dealing with a `SELECT` statement that returns relatively few rows and a tight inner loop, it is unlikely that there will be an appreciable difference between the two.  Adding a `FOR UPDATE` on the `SELECT` also gives you the opportunity to add a timeout clause if you don't want your script to block indefinitely if some other session happens to have one of the row you're trying to update locked.

Comment: Wouldn't the `FOR UPDATE` script run faster as it is effectively accessing the update via `ROWID` in the `WHERE CURRENT OF` clause?

Comment: @Ollie - Possible.  But the `SELECT` has to visit every row to set the lock attribute before it returns the first row so it will involve hitting every row a second time (though the second hit is likely to be on a cached object).  I'd expect the two to offset each other.  Plus, if the goal is to maximize speed, you'd write a single `UPDATE` statement or at least PL/SQL bulk operations, rather than a row-by-row cursor `FOR` loop.